# awgn command in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am unable to understand the command awgn in matlab.I considered the signal vector
 x=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10].The power of x is

pow_x=norm(x,2)^2/length(x)=38.5000

and it's value in dB is pow_xdb=10*log10(pow_x)=15.8546 dB

Now I want AWGN noise denoted by n with SNR of 30 dB wrt to signal x.So I use the command

n=awgn(x,snr,sigpower)=awgn(x,30,15.8546) and I get

n=[1.1055 2.3598 2.5568 4.1692 5.0625 5.7434 6.9149 8.0672 9.7021 10.5434]

The power of n is pow_n=norm(n,2)^2/length(n)=40.7517 and in dB is pow_ndb=10*log10(pow_n)=16.1015

When I can calculate SNR I get

SNR=10*log10(pow_x/pow_n)=-0.2469  dB and not 30 dB.

So,someone please help me though I use the command n=awgn(x,snr,sigpower)=awgn(x,30,15.8546) to get a AWGN signal vector whose SNR wrt to x is 30 dB why am I unable to generate it

Based upon Adam Sir's suggestion I tried running the program below and the answers I got are

t=0:0.01:1;
disp('Number of Samples');disp(length(t));

y=sin(2*pi*1*t);% Signal

y_pow=norm(y)^2/length(t);
disp('Power of y');disp(y_pow);
y_powdb=10*log10(y_pow);
disp('Power of y in db');disp(y_powdb);

y_noise=awgn(y,30,'measured');% Noisy Signal

n=y_noise-y;% Noise

n_pow=norm(n)^2/length(t);disp('Noise Power');disp(n_pow);
n_powdb=10*log10(n_pow);disp('Noise Power in db');disp(n_powdb);

SNR=20*log10(norm(y_noise)/norm(n));disp('The Signal to Noise Ratio is');disp((SNR));

Answers I got

Number of Samples
   101

Power of y
    0.4950

Power of y in db
   -3.0535

Noise Power
  4.9047e-004

Noise Power in db
  -33.0939

The Signal to Noise Ratio is
   30.0608

> > I tried this program several times and the SNR I got is not exactly 30 but a value in the neighbourhood of 30,is there any mistake in my approach,I am not getting the exact value

Answer (score 1):

It could be because of this reason:

**x** ... signal

**n** = awgn(x,snr) ... that's the resulting signal; signal **x** with added noise

Check it easily by subtracting clear signal from noisy signal: **only_noise = n - x;**

It works for me, hope that it helps you...

Adam

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir,based upon your suggestion I got the answers for the code

Comment: Adam Sir I modified the question I asked by including the code in it.Please help